# Generic Event Args In Interface

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0

I'm trying to save an object in a generic EventArgs class but because the EventHandler has an interface, I'm having difficulty accomplishing this.  Any way to get something like this working?

My EventArgs class:

```
public class PositionChangedEventArgs<T>
{
   public PositionChangedEventArgs(byte position, T deviceArgs)
   {
       Position = position;
       DeviceArgs = deviceArgs;
   }

   public byte Position { get; private set; }
   public T DeviceArgs { get; private set; }
}
```

Interface being used:

```
public interface IMoveable
{
    event EventHandler<PositionChangedEventArgs<T>> PositionChanged;
}
```

Example class usage:

```
public class SomeDevice : IMoveable
{
   public event EventHandler<PositionChangedEventArgs<DeviceSpecificEventMessageArgs>> PositionChanged; //Compiler doesn't like this
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change your interface definition to the following:

```
public interface IMoveable<T>
{
    event EventHandler<PositionChangedEventArgs<T>> PositionChanged;
}
```

You can consume it by passing the type to the interface like so:

```
public class SomeDevice : IMoveable<DeviceSpecificEventMessageArgs>
{
   public event EventHandler<PositionChangedEventArgs<DeviceSpecificEventMessageArgs>> PositionChanged; 
}
```

Comment: This. You had the interface define an event with a generic parameter that could not be defined when actually implementing the event concretely. If you make the whole interface generic to that T, you can then close the generic by saying you're implementing the entire interface for your event arg type.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you must declare the interface as generic:

```
public interface IMoveable<T>
{
    event EventHandler<PositionChangedEventArgs<T>> PositionChanged;
}
```